# How to clip actions based on state in RL environment for trading (and other tips to approach optimal trade execution)?

Tags: deep-rl, proximal-policy-optimization, soft-actor-critic, algorithmic-trading, observation-spaces

I’m currently trying to use RL to analyze price impact in financial markets for optimal trade execution and have coded up a custom gymnasium environment to do so. Now, I'm deciding on which RL algorithms to train with. I ran into a few problems while doing so and wanted to ask here if anyone has any experience/advice!

First of all, which algorithms would you recommend to try? Ideally I’d like to use SOTA algos just to compare the best of what’s possible in RL to other deterministic strategies. I’m thinking of using SAC and PPO, but am open to other recommendations or ideas.

My custom gymnasium environment describes a trader who needs to buy X shares of a stock in T time steps (the trader's position at time T needs to be exactly X, not more, not less). The state vector consists of the current position, time remaining, stock price, along with a few other variables and the action is a scalar describing the # of shares of stock to buy at each time step. Furthermore, the trader can only buy stocks but not sell, so the actions are >=0.

Since the agent's actions ideally are state-dependent (at time=0, I own 0 shares of stock, so my actions can be in [0,X], but if I already own Y (Y<X) shares of stock, my actions should be limited to [0,X-Y] because I can't sell later), is there a recommended way to implement this when using PPO/SAC? Or should I clip the action in the environment itself by taking the minimum between the action and remaining quantity (X-Y) in the step() function?

Furthermore, what's the best way to enforce the constraint of the ending position being exactly X? I currently don't restrict the action set (so at any time, the agent can choose any action in [0,X]), but if the position goes over 1000, the episode terminates with a reward of negative infinity. I feel like this is a crude way to try to teach the agent not to go over the position limit but am not sure if there's a better way to do so.

Also, one of my state variables is the price of the stock, which is a random process but may also fluctuate more depending on how much the agent decides to trade. In terms of defining the observation space, would using an unbounded interval be ok or would it be better to choose some large value that the price should realistically never go above? Also, how should I go about enforcing the price never goes below 0?

In addition, if anyone has any tips about hyperparameter tuning that would be great since I know that is a difficult and time-consuming part of using RL. I’m using gymnasium ActionRescale and NormalizeObservation wrappers to do normalization of actions/observations and have read the tips and tricks doc on the stable baselines 3 website, but running a first run with the stablebaselines-3 PPO implementation seems to be taking a long time. Thanks!